# Android: how to call methods of the activity from a listener

Tags: java, android, listener, bottombar

I'm using [BottomBar](https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar) in my main activity and I'm following the example code from github where he adds listeners to the tabs:

```
this.bottomBar = (BottomBar) findViewById(R.id.bottomBar);
bottomBar.setOnTabSelectListener(new OnTabSelectListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(@IdRes int tabId) {

        switch (tabId) {

            case R.id.tab_evaluate :
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Evaluate",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.tab_info:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"INfo",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            default:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Other",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }

    }
});
```

It's working perfectly and I see all the toasts.

My problem: in my main activity I have two methods which I would like to call depending on the selected tab:

```
private void showQrCodeView(){
    this.contentFrame.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    this.qrCodeReaderView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

private void hideQrCodeView(){
    this.contentFrame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    this.qrCodeReaderView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

To do so I trying this, which doesn't throw any errors but also doesn't work.

```
case R.id.tab_evaluate :
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Evaluate",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    MainActivity.this.showQrCodeView();
    break;
```

My question is how can I call my MainActivity methods from the `OnTabSelectListener`?

Answer (score 1):

Just figured out what was the problem: **the methods must be public**.